# Upgrading from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database

Should I be scared of upgrading the database to SQL Server 2008? 
Is it a simple auto-upgrade and everything works? 
Is it worth it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade from SQL Server 2005 to 2008 is a lot less "scary" than the upgrade from SQL Server 2000 to 2005.  There are fewer T-SQL enhancements this time around, and the tools to manage SQL Server are very similar (so less of a learning curve).

The one thing that most people forget to do is to change the compatibility level of their databases after the server has been upgraded; you need to do this in order to use the new features inside a particular database after the server has been upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to check out the features before asking a question like this.

Here's a [link](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/whats-new.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144267.aspx)